# Canceling authentication due to timeout

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postgresql-11

We have a nodejs application with about ~3k CCU using sequelize to connect to a postgres (version 11.9) database. In the first 5 weeks the app ran without any error, but this week we have a problem about connection, the database log outputs thousands of lines "FATAL:  canceling authentication due to timeout" and then all connections crashed. Logs in images below (sorry i have to hide path of project and ip for some security reasons). Thanks for any help!!!

[image: Databse log]

[image: Nodejs log]

Comment: And, did you get it sorted out?

Comment: Such thing can happen when pg driver in the app is older than DB version.

Comment: Did yo ever have this fixed?